404 Error Occurs When Making POST Requests via Firebase Function
After configuring CORS to allow requests from any origin to resolve a previous CORS issue, I no longer get CORS errors, but now a 404 error occurs when making POST requests. I’ve checked the URL multiple times, and it doesn’t seem to be incorrect. What steps should I take to troubleshoot this?
When I test it on localhost, it works fine, but after deploying to web hosting, an error occurs when sending requests.

            try {
                const response = await fetch('https://us-central1-nulligpt.cloudfunctions.net/api/hello', {
                    method: 'GET',
                });

                if (!response.ok) {
                    throw new Error('Network response was not ok.');
                }

                const text = await response.text();
                document.getElementById('response').innerText = text;
            } catch (error) {
                console.log('Request failed', error);
            }

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');

const app = express();


app.use(cors({
  origin: ['https://nulligpt.web.app', 'http://127.0.0.1:5500'],
}));


app.get('/hello', (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).send('Hello World');
});

exports.api = functions.https.onRequest(app);



Your route only handles GET requests using app.get:
app.get('/hello', (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).send('Hello World');
});

If you want to handle POST as well, you need a route that explicitly handles that, perhaps using app.post().  Or if you want to handle all HTTP verbs in a single route, maybe you want to use app.all().
